# MS SQL Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int and JOIN two Tables

Tags: php, sql

I get an error saying: ***"Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int
"***
when I try to run the code below, but I already converted the `ASSIGNED_ID` to int in php ?

The `$row["ID"]` number is small its 2 so there are no , or anything like that, I even added a replace code to remove any spaces, but it still doesn't work. Also both tables have the same ID (data type: int)

I would also like to know how I can join the two tables: `T_ASSIGNED` and `T_EQ` using  their `ID (int)` they both have it and it always matches

```
// SEND A SELECT QUERY TO MSSQL
$query = mssql_query('SELECT ID FROM [TestT].[dbo].[T_ASSIGNED] WHERE [A_T_N]=\'$contact_lastname\'');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($query);

if (strlen($row["ID"])<>0) {
// REMOVE ANY SPACES AND CONVERT ID TO INT
$ASSIGNED_ID = intval(str_replace(" ", "", $row["ID"]));
}else{
// IF NO ID IS FOUND MAKE ID BE ZERO
$ASSIGNED_ID =intval('0');
};


// FREE THE QUERY RESULT
mssql_free_result($query);

// ECHO THE ID
ECHO("TEST ID: ".$ASSIGNED_ID);

// GET THE T NUMBER IN THE T_EQ LOCATION
$query = mssql_query('SELECT EQ_T_N FROM [TestT].[dbo].[T_EQ] WHERE [ID]=\'$ASSIGNED_ID\'');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($query);

// ECHO THE EQ_T_N
echo(">".$row["EQ_T_N"]."<");

// FREE THE QUERY RESULT
mssql_free_result($query);
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
mssql_query('SELECT EQ_T_N FROM [TestT].[dbo].[T_EQ] WHERE [ID]="' . $ASSIGNED_ID .'"');
```

by using single quotes, you're using the text of `$ASSIGNED_ID`, not the value of that variable