# MSSQL JOIN the two tables below using WHERE

Tags: php, sql

How can I JOIN the two tables below using WHERE ?
I tried the following but I don't think that I'm doing it correctly:

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT T_EQ.[ID],T_ASSIGNED.[ID] FROM [TestTABLE].[dbo].[T_ASSIGNED] WHERE [T_ASSIGNED].[A_T_N]="' . $contact_lastname .'" JOIN T_EQ ON T_ASSIGNED.[ID] = T_EQ.[ID]');
```

This question is an extension to the question asked here: [MS SQL Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int and JOIN two Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694595/ms-sql-conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int-and)

Comment: A `JOIN` should be part of the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Place your `WHERE` statement at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT T_EQ.[ID],T_ASSIGNED.[ID] FROM [TestTABLE].[dbo].[T_ASSIGNED] JOIN T_EQ ON T_ASSIGNED.[ID] = T_EQ.[ID] WHERE [T_ASSIGNED].[A_T_N]="' . $contact_lastname .'" );
```

Comment: He should probably parameterise the query as well.

Comment: @Zane completely agree with you